# How to find a call is unanswered in iphone

Tags: iphone

If i make a call from an application using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1234567890"]];
```

How can i check if the call is answered or unanswered

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You cannot check this. When this URL is opened your application will be closed and phone app will be launched. Since you cannot access calls data from your app there is little you can do. This may be possible in jailbroken iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up a dialog when the app re-opens asking the user if the call went through.  You better have a good reason for wanting to know though or the user will be mighty annoyed!

Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: Or make the dialog box say "did your call have any major issues?"

Answer (score 0):

Not an iPhone app developer but is it possible to query the phone log the next time the app loads and check time on call or something and if it is over 20 seconds consider it completed or something like this?

Comment: It's not possible to access call log programatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to the iPhone phone from third party software. Luckily.

you can reffer

[How can I check missed call in iPhone using Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184023/how-can-i-check-missed-call-in-iphone-using-objective-c)