# D i modify calling iphone software?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

my question is:
would be feasible to modify the software to get calls? I intend to capture the action of the call attempt to operate accordingly.

Sorry for not being more explicit

Comment: This is hard to answer, since your question is not clear. What are you actually asking for? Which software do you intend to modify? Which action do you want to capture?

Comment: I try to modify the software is to make calla. I would like to capture the failure to respond to the call and act accordingly, either by sending a message, email, etc ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check missed call in iPhone using Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184023/how-can-i-check-missed-call-in-iphone-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

@user449303 
You cant modify the default apps comes with iPhone.
but you can handle the event like missed call,call ended,call failed etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to manipulate the method of making or receiving of phone calls on the iphone (using publically available APIs).  An app can initiate a phone call but the phone call will be made using the Apple call application.

Comment: thx for the answer and sorry for the poor question. I try to send a kind of message to the person who call me. Is it possible?

Comment: So if i wrap the apple call application in some way, it might be possible, isn't it? thx in advance

Comment: maybe if you jailbreak your phone but again there's no "approved" way to modify the call app.

Comment: @user449303 
you can make app which handles call events like missed call,call ended,etc.. and send msg to that number.